# In ack, can I define a type that is restricted by both extension and first line (two filtertypes)?

Tags: configuration, config, ack

If I understand correctly (from **Defining your own types** in `ack --man`), when I use `--type-set` in `.ackrc` (or at the command line) I can only use one "filtertype".  In my case, I'd like to match files with a particular extension that also have a pattern present in the first line.  I imagined it would look like this (perhaps without the `--type-set` in the middle:

```
--type-set
mytype:firstlinematch:my.regex.pattern...
--type-set
mytype:ext:myextension
```

If I do that, though, the linematch is ignored, because the type is replaced by the 2nd entry.*

I know multiple entries are allowed for `--type-add`, but that means this OR that condition must be true, rather than restricting to when both are true.

Is there a way to narrow using two filter types for a case like this?

- (If I'm right about that, then a warning would help when a definition is clobbered later in `.ackrc`.)

Answer (score 0):

Using `--type-add` as the second definition is not restrictive. If one defines `foo` file types as follows:

```
ack --type-set foo:.txt --foo bar
```

This finds all `txt` files with `bar` somewhere in the file. If one adds to this file type set a first line match:

```
ack --type-set foo:.txt --type-add foo:firstlinematch:/pr.*t/ --foo bar
```

This redefines the file type as all txt files AND any file containing the regex /pr.*t/ in its first line. Accordingly, it finds all `bar`s in that set of files. In other words, `type-add` is *add*s to the definition of files. The man file explicitly says:

> "Type specifications can be repeated and are ORed together."